# Text to ASCI Font generator

Tags: javascript, fonts

and sorry for the vague question title. Please read on to get a mental impression of my thoughts.

I want to create a program that takes a string as input and outputs the ASCI Images

Example- My string is "SAY HI"

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
    ------      /-------\     |||     |||   ------                             |
     ||        |||     |||    |||     |||   ||                                 |
     \\        |||__ __|||    |||__ _ |||   \\                                 | 
       ==\\    ||| _ _ |||        |||         ==\\                             |  
         ||    |||     |||        |||            ||                            |  
    ------     |||     |||        |||       ------                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
                                                                                |
                     |||    |||  [=========]       |||                          | 
                     |||_ __|||      |||           |||                          |
                     |||__ _|||      |||           |||                          |
                     |||    |||      |||           |||                          |
                     |||    |||      |||           ___                          | 
                     |||    |||  [=========]       |__|                         | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Possible approach to achieve this.

1) (Naive approach) I convinced myself that creating a 2-D character array for all the possible characters, store them, and upon entering the input string we check for individual characters and cout the already stored 2-D array respective to that character, we do this till we reach the string's end.

```
For Example: We store Char A as. 
char[][] =  
 .----------------. 
| .--------------. |
| |      __      | |
| |     /  \     | |
| |    / /\ \    | |
| |   / ____ \   | |
| | _/ /    \ \_ | |
| ||____|  |____|| |
| |              | |
| '--------------' |
 '----------------' 
Possible logic for this approach is.
foreach(str[i].....str [N])
   identifyCharacter();
   identifyTheCorrespondingCharacter2-DArray();
      iterateThroughEachRowInTheIdentifiedArray.
         printEachRowIn2-DArryInNewLine

same goes with B-Z and 0..9
```

Lets not talk about the efficiency and optimality, above approach is certainly far far away from optimal, certainly not scalable, if at all, Like what if we want to generate fonts of different sizes and all, This approach surely won't help.

2)Bombarded with enough confusions, and non-efficient-logic, not knowing what to call them, I searched for "Text to ASCI font generator", I tried to look up the web and browsing the first few links, got me towards a similar project on git.

https://github.com/patorjk/figlet.js

Which appeared scalable, and looks preety cool

http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20

What I meant by this solution is, its possible that if I use some specific language, it might make my job easier, just saying. I'm  ready to learn any new tool for this.

There, So I want to create a program that outputs ASCI Images for the netered string, same as the one in the that link I provided.

The idea is to create a ASCI garden, where the user enters the string and we generate the ASCI Images, furthermore we provide them the option to choose, say if the user enters the string "house", we create a ASCI house, and not just the ASCI Clone of the string house. I hope you understand about what I'm trying to say.

```
A house
        /\ 
       /  \        
      |....|
      |  []|
      ------
```

Well, Its not some awesomely innovative brilliant breakthrough, its just what I want to do with my free time, and just a motivation to learn some new tools, only if not possible with my present arsenal. (c++, PHP, Javascript).

Please let me know if you have any sincere suggestions for this, and also have the courtesy to let me know if this question is not appropriate here, I'll be happy to move it. I'm not sure about the appropriate tags that this question belongs, I'm in for the suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please narrow down your question, an pick a *single* language to ask about? Instead of tagging every language you're familiar with.

Comment: its been done. Google is your friend.

Comment: OK, My bad, any possible tag suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please remove that whole backstory. There's really no point in having that in the question. Just say something like _"I want to do X and Y for a personal project"_, if you must.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines:

```js
var letters = {
    a : [
        ' /-------\\ ',
        '|||     |||',
        '|||__ __|||',
        '||| _ _ |||',
        '|||     |||',
        '|||     |||'
    ],
    s : [
        ' ------',
        ' ||    ',
        ' \\\\    ',
        '   ==\\\\',
        '     ||',
        '------ '
    ], 
    y :  [
        '|||     |||',
        '|||     |||',
        '|||__ _ |||',
        '    |||    ',
        '    |||    ',
        '    |||    '
    ]
};

var text = "Say";
var lines = ['', '', '', '', '', ''];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){    // For each letter,
    var letter = text[i].toLowerCase();    // Get the current letter,
    for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++){              // For each line that the letters are high,
        lines[j] += letters[letter][j] + '   ';// Add the current line to the result.
    }            // Spacer between letters ^
};
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = lines.join("\n"); // Output the result.
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

You'd have to add some extra checks to check for non-existant characters, not to mention adding the rest of the characters manually, but you get the idea.

Keep in mind that `"\\"` in JS translates to `"\"` in the output. You'll need to double the backslashes, because they're escaping themselves.